# How to get notified when user clicks LIKE on your page (timeline layout)?

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

Up to now, the tab app automatically gets reloaded when user clicks "like". In new timeline fan pages it doesn't. How to catch that event?

Note that JavaScript SDK `edge.create` is working just for custom like buttons - not when users clicks default like button.

Comment: A bug is open
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386?browse=search_4f4f6b37647148015653034

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, but don't worry, it's a bug that the page is not refreshing after being liked. Here's the bug reported:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386?browse=search_4f500194bc1bd0293819428

However, I managed to do a workaround to detect if the page is still not using timeline by looking for an album called "Cover Photos" on the album list of that page. Here's a sample:

http://graph.facebook.com/-page_id-/albums?fields=name

You don't need a token unless the page isn't published yet.

The problem with this approach is that some pages still don't have cover picture yet, but it's the minority.